# Outlook 2007 closes immediately after opening

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, .net-framework, .net-2.0

Outlook 2007 opens up, then immediately closes. Event Viewer is showing:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.1433 - Fatal Execution Engine Error
>   (79FFEE24) (80131506)

I can't seem to find any hotfixes that will run and fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the .NET framework 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some buggy third-party add-ins installed. Try to start Outlook with */safe* command line switch.

Comment: After a while of tracking down errors, I found it was due to the Business Contact Manager add-in.